# Fast way to count the number of relationships for a node

Tags: java, neo4j

I am trying to count the number of outgoing relationships of a particular type a node has.  My code currently looks like this:

```
int count = 0;
for (Relationship r : node.getRelationships(RelationshipTypes.MODIFIES, Direction.OUTGOING))
{
   count++;
}
return count;
```

The return type of getRelationships is Iterable so I can't use size() or equivalent.  I am trying to avoid having to pull every relationship out of the database because some nodes have lots of relationships ( > 5 million).  Is there a faster way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The way neo4j stores relationships on disk for a node is in a linked list, and they do not keep any type of statistics for nodes or relationships. In order to get a count, you will have to go through all relationships for the node, of that type.

Even if you have a cache, with which they store it more efficiently, the system may still not provide a full picture. You method is the best method.

Comment: I was afraid that's what the answer was, but was hoping I was wrong.

Comment: Same here, I dislike it, however I have been through the Structure Neo4j stores the objects and there aren't any statistics stored on disk, and ALL relationships of a node are in a linked list on disk.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to store outgoing in a data structure and get the size of the structure. This may take more time when the objects are initialized but it seems like the easiest way to quickly get size.

Comment: This technique grows fast as the number of relationships you want to check also increases.

Comment: How does it grow fast? Is it due to resizing of a data structure or does getting the size of the struct have a high cost?

Comment: I mean you will need a data structure for each requirement.

Comment: That is necessarily true, to solve this specific problem it would be sufficient to implement a structure only for outbound connections. It isn't safe to assume he would implement this structure for every type of relationship for every node. We are providing a solution to a single problem.

Answer (score 0):

if `node.getRelationships(RelationshipTypes.MODIFIES, Direction.OUTGOING)` is returning a type of `Collection` then 
to know the number of outgoing relationships of a particular type a node has , you can simply use the following :

```
int count = node.getRelationships(RelationshipTypes.MODIFIES, Direction.OUTGOING).size();
```

Comment: This won't work because getRelationships returns Iterable, not a collection.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using the neo4j api. The other way would be to go with [ThinkerPop](http://www.tinkerpop.com/) gremlin query language which is available both for groovy and scala but they will do the same thing internally. As i know neo4j is giving you access trough an iterator because of performance reasons. For instance you could have million relationships but you want to paginate trough the results on the fly. It would be really be slow if Neo4J would return always a collection of relationships. That's why he returns a iterator and gives you access on the fly to the relationships. They are not retrieved from the DB until you need them.

So i would say NO. I hope i could help you.